# why my redis-server will restart automatically after kill -9?

Tags: linux, redis

my system is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and I use apt to install redis-server(redis_version:4.0.9), using **/etc/init.d/redis-server start** to run redis, redis will restart immediately after **kill -9 pid** operation, but I don't find anything relative to systemd, how can redis do that?

Comment: Have you tried stopping it using `/etc/init.d/redis-server stop` instead?

Comment: @mattfreake yeah it can work, but what I curious about is why the redis can restart automatically? any scripts put in /etc/init.d can make a auto restart?

Comment: Have you found out why? I have just encountered this problem recently.